# How to invoke pointer to member function from static member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I need to get a member function called by a standard function pointer, so I tried to abstract things like this:

```
class Sample {
public:
    virtual void doSomething(void) = 0;
};


class A : public Sample {
    void doSomething(void);     // details omitted
};

class B : public Sample {
    void doSomething(void);     // details omitted
};


class Executor {
public:
    Executor(Sample *sample)
     : func(&sample->doSomething)
    {
    }

    static void *execute(void *data) {
        Executor *pX = data;

        (pX->*func)();          // error invalid access of func from static function

        (pX->*pX->func)();      // error pointer to member type 'void (Sample::)()'
                                //       incompatible with object type 'Executor'
    }

private:
    void (Sample::*func)(void);
};



int main(void) {
    A   myA;
    B   myB;
    Executor x0(&myA);
    Executor x1(&myB);

    externallyInvoke(&Executor::execute, &x0);
    externallyInvoke(&Executor::execute, &x1);
}
```

`externallyInvoke` is a Linux system call, which takes a function pointer and a data pointer. 
I'd like to use a static member function together with a this-pointer as data.

... and I don't want classes like `A` or `B` to have static members. So my idea was to create an interface like class `Sample`, that gets extended by `A` and `B`.

My problem is that I don't know how to invoke the pointer to member function from inside the `Executor::execute` function.

Comment: can't access member variable from a static function - what is not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need two objects inside `execute` - one is the instance of `Executor` which will supply `func`, and the other is an instance of (a class derived from) `Sample` on which `func` will be invoked. So you have to store *the object* inside `Executor`, not the function:

```
class Executor {
public:
    Executor(Sample *sample)
     : obj(sample)
    {
    }

    static void *execute(void *data) {
        Executor *pX = static_cast<Executor*>(data);

        pX->obj->doSomething();
    }

private:
    Sample *obj;
};


int main() { // note that `void main()` is not legal C++
    A   myA;
    B   myB;
    Executor x0(&myA);
    Executor x1(&myB);

    externallyInvoke(&Executor::execute, &x0);
    externallyInvoke(&Executor::execute, &x1);
}
```

A pointer to member function (such as your original `void (Sample::*func)()`) identifies a function within a class, but does not store the object. You'd still need to provide one to call the function.

Comment: shouldn't `x0(myA)` be `x0(&myA)`?

Comment: @Wimmel Yes of course, I copied that from the OP before it was fixed in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Angew I obviously was looking to reinvent a functor, but your solution is quite cleaner and for so: lovely :) THX

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to also pass an instance of`Sample` on which to call the function (since it's a pointer to a member of `Sample`). There's a few ways to bring the instance along. You could make it a member of `Executor`, pass a `std::pair*` as `data` or you could combine the function pointer and the instance as a functor. Here's a lamda based approach for the latter. Lamda has the advantage of being more versatile. It's possible to do much more than just call one member of one class. As a bonus, this approach does not avoid visibility rules, although that means `doSomething` may not be private (or it must be called through the parent pointer).

```
template<class F>
class Executor {
    F f;
public:
    Executor(F f): f(f){}
    static void *execute(void *data) {
        Executor<F> *pX = static_cast<Executor<F>*>(data);
        pX->f();
        return this; // not quite sure what you intend to return, but just to make this a well formed function...
    }
};


int main() {
    A   myA;
    B   myB;
    auto callback0 = [myA]{
        myA.doSomething();
    };
    auto callback1 = [myB]{
        myB.doSomething();
    };
    Executor<decltype(callback0)> x0(callback0);
    Executor<decltype(callback1)> x1(callback1);

    externallyInvoke(&Executor::execute, &x0);
    externallyInvoke(&Executor::execute, &x1);
}
```

Comment: `func` is a member, it cannot be used in a `static` method.

Comment: @user657267 ah, gotcha. Fixed the answer.

Comment: How does that fix the answer? He wants to call a member function pointer over a `static` method, it simply isn't possible, making it `public` changes nothing.

Comment: @user657267, damn not my day. I didn't notice that it was not only a member but also a pointer to a member function of another class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with an external system call, you basically have to reinvent `std::function` yourself. No problem, here at Stack Overflow we're the masters of reinventing existing technology. So...

First, the interface:

```
struct FunctionStateBase
{
    virtual ~FunctionStateBase() {}
    virtual void Invoke() = 0;
};

extern "C" void InvokeAndDelete(void * data)
{
    auto state = static_cast<FunctionStateBase *>(data);
    state->Invoke();
    delete state;
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```
externallyInvoke(&InvokeAndDelete, MakeFunction(&A::doSomething, &myA));
```

Now we need to implement `MakeFunction`:

```
template <typename> struct FunctionState;

template <typename C, typename R>
struct FunctionState<R (C::*)()> : FunctionStateBase
{
    R (C::ptmf_*)();
    C * obj_;

    FunctionState(R (C::ptmf*)(), C * obj) : obj_(obj), ptmf_(ptmf) {}

    virtual void Invoke() { (C->ptmf_)(); }
};

template <typename C, typename R>
FunctionState<R (C::*)()> MakeFunction(R (C::*ptmf)(), C * obj)
{
    return new FunctionState<R (C::*)()>(ptfm, obj);
}
```

At this point we're managing the life time of the function wrapper manually, and note that `InvokeAndDelete` actually *takes ownership* of the function state. In proper C++, we would wrap the entire system call invocation in a class that would encapsulate the lifetime management internally.

You can add further specializations for member functions that take arguments; you just need to store a copy of the arguments in the state.