# Calling function pointer from static function

Tags: c++

Inside some class called `Light`, I have a static function.

I would like to "fire" a delegate from it ,

```
Inside Light.h

static float intepreterDelegate(char *arg){



        // here I need to call the function pointer inside Light itself
        Light b;
        return b.fpAction(arg); //  ** error: "expected unqualified id"
        };

    float (*fpAction)(char*) = 0 ; // the actual pointer
```

How would I create the right syntax for this ?

```
b.(*fpAction)("arg");
```

**EDIT:**

```
(b.*b.fpAction)(arg);
```

ERROR: right hand operator to * has non.

Comment: I don't know what MVCE error is, not the whole world is a c++ programmers. You have a concrete answer ?

Comment: You need a member function pointer, and you have to declare it before using it inside the `interpretDelegate` function.

Comment: @Quentin can you explain ?

Comment: @Curnelious He was asking, that you supply us with [mcve].

Comment: Possible Duplicate or Related: [How to invoke pointer to member function when it's a class data member?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6316751/514235)

Comment: @iammilind yea a possible duplicate, but   (b.*b.fpAction)(arg); still gives an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke pointer to member function from static member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604738/how-to-invoke-pointer-to-member-function-from-static-member-function)

Comment: I don't understand what your code actually is. You say `intepreterDelegate` is inside a class, but what you have posted doesn't appear to be. I assume there is more definition around this you haven't shared. Next you seem to be having trouble with `return b.fpAction(arg);`. But I don't know how `fpAction` is defined, or where because there aren't enough details in the question. ""expected unqualified id"" often happens because of missing or extra semicolons or similar, so there's not enough info to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float (*fpAction)(char*) = 0 ; // the actual pointer
```

this creates a regular function pointer, not a member-function pointer.
change to

```
float (Light::*fpAction)(char*) = 0 ;
```

calling this function pointer on the `Light` instance named `b`

```
float result = (b.*b.fpAction)("arg");
```

P.S.
if you're wondering what the double b is doing there.
it's really (b.*(b.fpAction))("arg");
b.fpAction identifies the pointer as member of Light instance b.
(b.*pointer)("arg")  calls the functionpointer using 'b' as 'this' value inside the function.

Comment: Thank you! this worked , but now setting the delegate like this :  void Light::setDelegate( float(*fp)(char*))
{
    fpAction=fp;
}  gives error, I guess I am doing it wrong.

Comment: you need to change the delegate call to also use the proper prototype for a member-function pointer:

float (Light::*fpAction)(char*)

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. Can you please show how to set my delegate right ? ( I am very new to C++)  , this is the delegate function void Light::setDelegate( float(fp)(char)) { set here  }

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong type:

```
float (*fpAction)(char*) = 0 ; // the actual pointer
```

Should be

```
float (Light::*fpAction)(char*) = 0 ; // the actual pointer
```

and then

```
fpAction = &Light::myMethod;
```

and

```
static float intepreterDelegate(char *arg){
    Light b;
    return (b.*fpAction)(arg);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/RPNBXN)

Comment: Thank you very much , but :  return (b.*fpAction)(arg);  gives error:" invalid use of faction" , even if I change to exactly what you have showed here.